# Nested Result while using CakePhp Containable

Tags: cakephp, containable, cakephp-2.x

I am not sure about the question title but tried to explain more below. Thanks in advance for all who helps me.

I sampled the tables to simplify my questions.

**DB Tables**

- News: news_id, title
- Comments: comment_id, news_id, content, created (timestamp)

Users are posting comments to the news. In a search with the input of "date interval 01.10.2015 - 05.11.2015", the result should include: the news which has been commented between this interval. And comment_count should be shown next to the title on the screen. This comment_count is not whole comment_count, only the count between this dates.

To do that, I ran the query first in comments. Then count comments. Then group by news_id.

```
$Data = $this->Comment->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'News.news_id','News.title'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            "Comment.created >=" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days")) //yesterday's commented news
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'News' => array(
                'Comment => array(
                    'fields' => array('COUNT(Comment.id) as comment_count'),
                )
            )
        ),
        'group' => array('News.title')
    ));
```

The result is below with too much nesting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [News] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 27
                    [title] => sample news title
                    [News] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 27
                            [title] => sample news title
                            [Comment] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [News_id] => 27
                                            [Comment] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Comment_count] => 1
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

In conclusion, to reach comment_count, I have to write the nestings manually. However I would like to reach it in the same level with first [title] node.

```
$JsonData [] = array(
            "id" =>  $Item["News"]["id"],
            "title" =>  $Item["News"]["title"],
            "comment_count" =>  $Item["News"]["News"]["Comment"][0]["Comment"][0]["comment_count"]
            );
```

How can I reduce the life-long nesting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should name your table id like `id` not `news_id`. For your question, I'm not sure from what controller you are displaying news, IMO this should be done in `NewsController`. Here is how you can retrieve your news with comments count from previous day:

```
$Data = $this->News->find('all', array(
'fields' => array(
    'News.id', 
    'News.title',
    'COUNT(Comment.id) as comment_count'
),
'group' => array('News.id'),
'joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'comments',
        'alias' => 'Comment',
        'conditions' => array(
            'News.id = Comment.news_id',
            'Comment.created >=' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days"))
        )
    )
)
```

));

This should give you resulting array like this:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'News' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'title' => 'New news'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'comment_count' => '2'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'News' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'title' => 'Seconds news'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'comment_count' => '1'
    )
),
)
```

Then you can get your comment count(assuming through foreach loop):

```
... "comment_count" => $Data[0]['comment_count'] ...
```

You should look [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count) it might be useful to you.

Comment: Hi @skywalker, Thanks for your great help. Actually, in my db, it was already id instead of news_id but I gave it here to simplify my problem.
It seems my problem solved but is there anyway without using join. I would prefer to use Cake's existing model-relationships. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, you can try with counterCache, but that way you can't get comments for given period of time, only number of total comments for given news. I am not sure if you can do this other then using `join`.

Comment: In that result, I don't need the comment details. I need only commentCount with the given date interval. Let me try counterCache. Thanks.